# Real Time SQL Server Analysis Services Cube Processing Report

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssrs

I would like to know if there is a way to generate a report to determine which SQL Server Analysis Services cubes are processing using SQL Server Reporting Services? I would like to be able to run this report without affecting the cube process, in real-time. The end product of this process is to create a way to let end users know the a report cannot be created because cube is processing.

Comment: Are you looking to see weather the cube's are processing or are you trying to see what the latest records that you have available in your cubes?

Comment: I'd like to know weather the cube is processing

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are worried about the downtime due to cube processing. 
As detailed in the post below, the downtime, due to processing, is very minimal .

http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2011/06/can-you-query-a-ssas-cube-while-it-is-processing/

In the comments section, there is an approach mentioned by which you can reduce this downtime (with few caveats) by using one server to do the processing and then sync the DBs.

If you still want to do the report, you can follow the approach suggested here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899250/how-to-determine-which-ssas-cube-is-processing-now