# Real-Time SSAS cube status notification

Tags: ssas, cube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Real Time SQL Server Analysis Services Cube Processing Report](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29302/real-time-sql-server-analysis-services-cube-processing-report)

I would like to know if there is a way to generate a report to determine which SQL Server Analysis Services cubes are processing using SQL Server Reporting Services? I would like to be able to run this report without affecting the cube process. The reason I would like to know this information is because I would like to setup a notification for the users to let them know the cube is processing can reports cannot be ran at the time of the processing.